# Using gdal ReadAsArray or Arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray on python 2.6 32bit without it crashing

Tags: arcpy, raster, gdal, array

I am trying to run ReadAsArray on an entire raster and on a single band, python will crash without an error message when trying to do either.

Is there a way I can create a 3d array without having to make the switch to 64bit python?

I was trying to use arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray but that would also crash. It works with a .TIFF file but not with a .PIX file. I need it to work with a .PIX file. I would rather use arcpy and not have to install gdal on the other machines at work. With that being said if gdal is the only option I am okay wit installing it. The image im working with is a 65mb pix file
Even if I try the following it will close:

```
    raster_array.ReadAsArray(0,0,10,10)
```

Comment: How big is the raster (cells)? It's trying to hold an entire array in memory and so may be limited by your current hardware.

Comment: If the data file in question is larger than two gigabytes uncompressed (give or take a few hundred megabytes), you are probably out of luck. 32-bit applications that try to read such a large dataset into memory will run out of space as 32 but programs only have 2 gigabytes of addressable memory on Windows.

Comment: the pix image is only 65mbs and im trying to just take in one band I dont think a single band could cause that much trouble